# Chartjs Doughnut Chart smooth animation in countdown

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, charts, chart.js

I am using doughnut chart from Chart.js to show 60 seconds timer chart.

Gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BvK8.jpg

```
options = {
    tooltips: {enabled: false},
    cutoutPercentage: 75,
    animation: {duration: 1}
};

data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [this.percentage, 100 - this.percentage],
            backgroundColor: [this.color, this.fillColor]
        },
    ]
};
```

On every second, I am updating the chart to reflect seconds. The timer start from 60 seconds and goes to 0. The current animation feels like ticking. I want the animation to look smooth as a sweeping clock instead of ticking.

How can I achieve sweep animation? Since the chart is redrawn after each second, how can I maintain the last position and update from that position?

Comment: The "duration" parameter must be in milliseconds. You set it to "1" you must set it to 1000 :http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html

Comment: Hi @Arkerone, on setting the duration to 1000, when chart updates, it starts from 0 instead of the last position.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using

```
        const data = this.getDataSet();
        this.doughnut.chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = data.backgroundColor;
        this.doughnut.chart.data.datasets[0].data = data.data;
        this.doughnut.chart.update();
```